# "Spikes" are created when I add a sub surface modifier to my model, even though everything in edit mode seems to be alright

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

Just like my title says, I add a sub surf modified to my model and I get these weird spikes. Its like an intersection gone wrong but I am not sure what is going wrong and what I should even be looking for... Lots of 3D experience, but very little Blender experience.

I was having trouble with duplicate edges just before this started happening, so I deleted all of the bottom edges and started over. Its built pretty simply so I am not sure where its going wrong... Quite simply I just want the bottom edge to be smooth, so that is my ultimate goal.

Also, on a side note, not sure what the red lines are around the other bottom edge. I believe it is a bevel or fillet of some sort but I don't remember what I did to get it on there...

Thanks in advance[image: ![Wire Frame Edit Mode]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnIRv.png)
[[image: Material Edit Mode]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vg7H.png)
[[image: Active Render w Spikes]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpWqr.png)

Comment: The red lines are edges that you marked either as sharp or as seam, to clear them use ctrl+e and select clear sharp or clear seam if you need to do that.

Comment: Regarding the spikes, have you tried to remove doubles? That might be causing the spikes.

Comment: I did try removing doubles. I did that command to see if there were extra vertices, which it says there weren't. Then I made sure I had no duplicate edges as well. Thank you for the information about the red edge!

Comment: Could you upload a copy of the blend file so I can take a look at it?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iDSUKmJChUt5ypqBATz5WtVsuo68jz5-?usp=sharing

Comment: Not sure how to upload files but that's a link to a drive file with the model. Thanks

Comment: I applied remove doubles and changed the merge disance to 0.030 and it merged 18 vertices. That resolved the spikes issue. Your main problem is that the overall topology of your mesh is not ideal for subdivision. For clean subdivision your model should be predominantly quads.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, could you explain a little more about this process (I am at work right now otherwise I would try it out). I assume you do the "remove doubles" and click F6 to bring up the sub menu? Again, I am fairly new to the game... Thank you for the helpful information and answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the spikes press  <kbd>Space</kbd>  search for "remove doubles" then hit  <kbd>F6</kbd>  to open the setting popover and adjust the merge distance to something like 0.03 to merge vertices that are very close to each other. That should take core of the spikes

Your main problem is that the overall topology of your mesh is not ideal for subdivision. For clean subdivision your model should be predominantly quads.

There is a good article on different types of modeling by Gleb Alexandrov that you can view [Here](https://www.creativeshrimp.com/3d-modeling-styles.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Samir Rahamtalla pointed out, I simply needed to add a value to the "merge distance" after using the "remove doubles" command. The value .03 worked well for me. Thanks again Samir!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/65529)

Comment: I tried to figure out how to do this without his answer being an answer (it was just a comment and there seemed to be no way to change it). This is like my third day on S.E. so I apologize I am trying my best! :p