# Surface Deform Modifier causing Spikes in Mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers, armature, error

I've been creating my own Spider-Man 3D model in different sections with the eyes, outer webbing and logos all separate to the main base mesh. After applying the Surface Deform modifier to the webs with the target as the main body, these spikes appear.
I cannot find any solution to this. The only solution I have tried is the SubSurf Modifier (both Simple and Catmull-Clark). And all transformations have been applied to both meshes in their default position.
I also cannot edit the modifier after applying it as I intend on using the model to animate with.

Before:
[image: Webbing without spikes and no modifiers applied]

After:
[image: Webbing with spikes and the surface deform modifier applied with the target mesh as the main body]

Comment: Hello, what are you trying to achieve with this Surface Deform? It's not clear...

Comment: They're places where the surface deform didn't get a clean bind.  The simplest solution is to assign the stray vertices to a vertex group and do a high strength, high iteration corrective smooth on that vertex group.

Comment: This is a similar question with possible answers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121969/spikes-are-created-when-i-add-a-sub-surface-modifier-to-my-model-even-though

Comment: I have tried the vertex group solution and when moving the mesh with the armature, the spikes appeared again, stretching to the original position of the spiking vertex. I do not have a screenshot of this but the problem remains - like I said, the solution cannot only be for the stationary model as I need it to animate with.

To answer what I'm trying to achieve here:
I am trying to keep the webbing to the same position on the mesh and deform along with the mesh as it is animating. I also do not want the spikes.